# flutter web set splash by url

Tags: splash-screen, flutter-web

Now I have a splash in my index.html:

```
    <body>

<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }


</script>

<img src="img/splash2.png" class="center"/>
```

How can I change the body according to the current url? I want to show different splash images for different pages.

Comment: Any luck with this? Wanted to try something exactly similar

Comment: @MuhammadMohsinAjmal We can add a script tag in the end of the body, and there use js to change the splash image shown. But I still didn't try it.